# Getting an average of span of dates when columns are the same but rows are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, datetime-format

I need help getting an average for lead times on service calls. So here is what i am currently working with.

```
           ***name           Date_Assigned      Date_Completed***   

            jon                  8/17/2017           8/20/2017
            jon                  9/10/2017           9/11/2017
            lucy                 8/5/2017            8/5/2017 
            jon                  8/19/2017           9/27/2017
```

I would like to find out:

```
        1.) What the average service lead time for everyone collectively is.
        2.) What the average service lead time per name is.
```

From what i have tried, i have to make the date format and cast it as datetime. but cannot seem to find the right solution! Can anyone help me out??? I am using SQL management Studio or t-sql syntax. Thank you!

Comment: Is it safe to assume this data is already in a table, or is this just a text file?

Comment: data is already in a table.. Bulk inserted from a .csv.

Comment: As dates, or as varchars?

Comment: dates, recently converted them to datetimes to try and satisfy formatting guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `avg` window function is supported you can use,

```
select distinct name
,avg(datediff(day,date_assigned,date_completed)) over(partition by name) as avg_per_name
,avg(datediff(day,date_assigned,date_completed)) over() as avg_overall
from tbl
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helps out a lot! exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
select name,
       avg ( datediff(day, date_assigned, date_completed) )
from t
group by grouping sets ( (name), () );
```

This puts the overall average in a separate row with a `NULL` value for `name`.

Comment: Missing the AVG, Gordon.  Neat solution though.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Setup table
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @temp table
(
    Name varchar(50),
    Date_Assigned datetime,
    Date_Completed datetime
)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT      
        'jon' , '8/17/2017'           ,'8/20/2017' UNION SELECT ALL
        'jon' , '9/10/2017'           ,'9/11/2017' UNION SELECT ALL
        'lucy', '8/5/2017'            ,'8/5/2017'  UNION SELECT ALL
        'jon' , '8/19/2017'           ,'9/27/2017'


select name, AVG(datediff(day, Date_Assigned, Date_Completed)) from @temp group by name
union select 'ALL', AVG(datediff(day, Date_Assigned, Date_Completed)) from @temp
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help!